# How many possible sets we can get?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can the power set of the set $\{1,2,\cdots ,n\}$ be partitioned into two sets $S_1,S_2$ such that; $$ \bigcup_{X\in S_1} X=\{1,2,\cdots ,n\}$$ where the minimum cardinality of each element of $S_1$ is $k>1$

For example when $n=3, k=2$, one acceptable $S_1$ would be

$$S_1 = \Big\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,2,3\} \Big\}$$

**My question is:**

Can we find a general formula for number of such partitions as a function of $n$ and $k$?

**My attempt:**

I recently found that it has something to do with [*Dedekind* numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number). If we
consider all possible strings of length $n$ ,place $1$ in the place of $k$-th number if $k$-th number is present in a $S_1$ and $0$ otherwise. Like, for $S_1= \{\{1,2\},\{1,3\}\}$ we have `110` and `101`. Now, consider a function which will give output $0$ or $1$ , when the string is accepted then output will be $1$ and if not then $0$. *Observe* that, if a string is accepted then also any string bigger than the accepted one is also a accepted string. So actually counting the number of functions $f:\{0,1\}^n\to \{0,1\}$ which are *monotone* are the number of possible such sets(haven't considered the condition that union of all subsets equals to $\{1,2,\cdots ,n\}$ ). Which is *Dedekind number*. Now, if consider the condition that the union covers the set $\{1,2\cdots ,n\}$ then we can use the method of counting number of onto functions and get the desired number of ways $$\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}M(n-i)$$
where $M(n)$ is the $n$-th *Dedekind number*.

Note:$S_2$ is of no use, just stated.

Comment: Is $S_2$ really relevant in any way?

Comment: @Arthur if this is the same problem I am thinking of then the sets of $S_2$ are all complements of sets in $S_1$. But it has been years since my undergraduate combinatorics course.

Comment: "The power set" of what set?  It looks like it has to contain $\mathbb{N}$.  Is it $\mathbb{N}$?  I find this question unclear.

Comment: @Arthur No, it's not.

Comment: Power set of the set $\{1,2,\cdots ,n\}$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Joe It _is_ off topic. Not because it isn't a math question, but because it lacks [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Comment: @Joe FFR, misspelling famous mathematicians' names probably does not impress anyone :)  *Dedekind* is the man. I've already fixed it for you.

Answer (score 2):

There are $2^n-n-1$ sets that are candidates for $S_1$ so there are $2^{2^n-n-1}$ candidates for $S_1$.  We are asking how many ways there is to select some set of them with union all of $[1,n]$.  It looks easier to count the sets that do not include some element and subtract, using inclusion-exclusion.  There are $2^{n-1}-(n-1)-1$ sets missing $n$ and $n2^{2^{n-1}-(n-1)-1}$ sets missing one number, but we have double counted the sets missing two numbers.  Using inclusion-exclusion we get $$2^{2^n-n-1}+\sum_{m=1}^{n-2}(-1)^m{n \choose m}2^{2^{n-m}-(n-m)-1}$$

Comment: I don't think that $\{2,3\}$ is a choice for $S_1$? The way that I am reading the question $S_1$ is to be an element of the powerset. i.e. $S_1$ would have to be a set of sets. Moreover, $S_1$ would have to have the property that the union of it's elements was the entire set $\{1,2 \dots n \}$.

Comment: @Mason: I had misread the problem, will update.

Comment: You are welcome to do this. I plan to wait for the OP to rephrase this question in a more understandable way. I think you might have misread the problem because it was written in a way that made it easy to do so...

Comment: @Mason:  I had just missed that we were looking for a subset of the power set of $[1,n]$ with union all of $[1,n]$.

Comment: No doubt. I edited the question twice (with pretty basic stuff: removing unneeded context as was the suggestion of Arthur above) and only because I really enjoy combinatorics questions like these and I hope that OP sticks around and continues to use this site. But I feel that there are many ways of expressing these types of question. For example (as noted by the OP) we can talk powersets but also we can talk binary strings. 
The burden of presenting this question in a way that it is accessible must fall on the OP.